# gmapsfx connected two point with a dash

Tags: java, intellij-idea, model-view-controller, gmaps.js

Hello I would like to connecte two point with a dash in java with gmaps.
But the point are insert when the user click on the map.

I have actually that code in my controller

```
public class Controller implements Initializable, MapComponentInitializedListener  {
    private int VitesseRef;
    private double HauteurRef;
    private DroneJava python;

    private int id=0;

    @FXML
    private GoogleMapView mapView;


    @FXML
    private TextField Vitesse;


    @FXML
    private TextField Hauteur;

    @FXML
    private TableView<Cordonnée> TabValue;

    private GoogleMap map;

    private List<Point> Point;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        mapView.addMapInializedListener(this);
        Vitesse.setText(String.valueOf(VitesseRef));
        Vitesse.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
            {
                if (newPropertyValue)
                {
                    System.out.println("Textfield on focus");
                }
                else
                {
                    VitesseRef= Integer.parseInt(Vitesse.getText());
                    System.out.println("Textfield out focus V = "+VitesseRef);
                }
            }
        });
        Hauteur.setText(String.valueOf(HauteurRef));
        Hauteur.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean oldPropertyValue, Boolean newPropertyValue)
            {
                if (newPropertyValue)
                {
                    System.out.println("Textfield on focus H");
                }
                else
                {
                    HauteurRef= Double.parseDouble(Hauteur.getText());
                    System.out.println("Textfield out focus H = "+HauteurRef);

                }
            }
        });

        TableColumn<Cordonnée, Integer> IDColumn = new TableColumn("Id");
        IDColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));

        TableColumn<Cordonnée, Type_Point> TypeColumn = new TableColumn("Type");
        TypeColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Type"));
        TypeColumn.setCellFactory(ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn(Type_Point.values()));


        TableColumn<Cordonnée, Double> LatColumn = new TableColumn("Latitude");
        LatColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Latitude"));
        LatColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double object) {
                return String.valueOf(object);
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string) {
                return Double.valueOf(string);
            }
        }));

        TableColumn<Cordonnée, Double> LongColumn = new TableColumn("Longitude");
        LongColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Longitude"));
        LongColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double object) {
                return String.valueOf(object);
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string) {
                return Double.valueOf(string);
            }
        }));

        TableColumn<Cordonnée, Double> AltColumn = new TableColumn("Hauteur");
        AltColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Altitude"));
        AltColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double object) {
                return String.valueOf(object);
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string) {
                return Double.valueOf(string);
            }
        }));

        TableColumn<Cordonnée, Integer> VitColumn = new TableColumn("Vitesse");
        VitColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Vitesse"));
        VitColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Integer object) {
                return String.valueOf(object);
            }

            @Override
            public Integer fromString(String string) {
                return Integer.parseInt(string);
            }
        }));

        TableColumn<Cordonnée, Double> DiaColumn = new TableColumn("Diametre");
        DiaColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("Diametre"));
        DiaColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double object) {
                return String.valueOf(object);
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string) {
                return Double.valueOf(string);
            }
        }));

        TableColumn Action = new TableColumn("Action");
        TableColumn Up = new TableColumn("Up");
        TableColumn Down = new TableColumn("Down");
        TableColumn Delete = new TableColumn("Delete");
        Action.getColumns().addAll(Up,Down,Delete);

        TabValue.getColumns().addAll(IDColumn,TypeColumn,LatColumn,LongColumn,AltColumn,VitColumn,DiaColumn,Action);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapInitialized() {

        //Set the initial properties of the map.
        MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();

        mapOptions.center(new LatLong(44.84062305077133, -0.5831479278476763))
                .overviewMapControl(true)
                .panControl(false)
                .rotateControl(false)
                .scaleControl(false)
                .streetViewControl(false)
                .zoomControl(true)
                .zoom(12);

        map = mapView.createMap(mapOptions);


        map.addMouseEventHandler(UIEventType.click, (GMapMouseEvent event) -> {
            LatLong latLong = event.getLatLong();
            System.out.println("Latitude: " + latLong.getLatitude());
            System.out.println("Longitude: " + latLong.getLongitude());
            MarkerOptions markerOptions1 = new MarkerOptions();
            markerOptions1.position(latLong);
            Marker joeSmithMarker = new Marker(markerOptions1);
            map.addMarker( joeSmithMarker );


            Cordonnée tmp = new Cordonnée(id,null,latLong.getLatitude(),latLong.getLongitude(),HauteurRef,VitesseRef);
            Point tmp1 = new Point(tmp,joeSmithMarker);
            id++;
            Point.add(tmp1);
            TabValue.getItems().add(tmp);
        });


    }

    public Controller(){
        Point = new ArrayList<Point>();
        VitesseRef=3;
        HauteurRef=2.5;
    }
```

and that controller run on that application :
[actual application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cLji.gif)

and i want to have that :
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKD1O.gif)

So for did that i test the MapShare but i cant find some exemple or documentation on it. So actually i don't know how link my point and i would like to have one exemple to test and undestood how it's work

Answer (score 0):

"But the point are insert when the user click on the map."

You will have to move to javascript.

Follow this example:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple

Essentially:

```
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
          {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
          {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
          {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
          {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
        ];
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });
```

You can draw a lot of things, but always take in account the load of points you will use. Use agrupations and so on.
Btw, your app loos nice.